# ANR Happend when updating viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-handler

I am getting below ANR while trying to update image view pager. Does anyone have an idea ? below is my code. I suspect when I do the setcurrentItem getting this `ANR : Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 5.`

```
private void setRelavantColourPic(ValueList valueList){
   if(valueList.getPictureId() != 0 && productImages != null && productImages.size() > 0){
       i = 0;

       for (ProductPictureList productPictureList : productImages ){
           int pictureId =  Integer.parseInt(productPictureList.getPictureId());
           i ++;
           if(pictureId == valueList.getPictureId()){
               foundIndex = i-1;
           }
       }



       mDelayHandler.postDelayed(
               mRunnable =   new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       mProductImageViewPager.setCurrentItem(foundIndex);
                   }
               }, 1);
     //  mDelayHandler.post(mRunnable);

   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a Runnable inside another Runnable?

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer Updated the code still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is recursing and blocking the main thread. Try removing the below statement,

```
mDelayHandler.post(mRunnable);
```

it will work.